# How do I get the sum of all content when parsing an XML tag in Ruby?

Tags: xml, ruby, parsing, combinators

I have some XHTML (but really any XML will do) like this:

```
<h1>
  Hello<span class='punctuation'>,</span>
  <span class='noun'>World<span class='punctuation'>!</span>
</h1>
```

How do I get the full content of the `<h1/>` as a String in Ruby?  As in:

```
assert_equal "Hello, World!", h1_node.some_method_that_aggregates_all_content
```

Do any of the XML frameworks ([Nokogiri](http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/tree/master), [libxml-ruby](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/), &c.) have this sort of thing built-in?  If not, I feel like a Y-Combinator might the right tool for the job, but I can't quite figure out what it would look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Nokogiri you can just ask for the `text` of a node.  The issue I see when doing that though is that all of the whitespace and newlines that are in that node will be returned, so you might want to strip those out (likely a better way to do that than what I did for this example).

Here is a sample:

```
def test_nokogiri_text
  value = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(<<-HTML_END)
    "<h1>
      Hello<span class='punctuation'>,</span>
      <span class='noun'>World<span class='punctuation'>!</span>
     </h1>"
  HTML_END

  h1_node = value.search("h1").first
  assert_equal("Hello, World!", h1_node.text.split(/\s+/).join(' ').strip)
end
```

Comment: If I'm going to be turning all the newlines into spaces anyway (which is totally fine, since XML treats them as equivalent), then h1_note.text.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').strip works the same and is a little faster, since it doesn't need to create as many new objects.

Answer (score 2):

Nokogiri's [Nokogiri::XML::Node#content](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#M000445) will do it:

```
irb(main):020:0> node
=> <h1>
  Hello<span class="punctuation">,</span>
  <span class="noun">World<span class="punctuation">!</span>
</span>
</h1>
irb(main):021:0> node.content
=> "\n  Hello,\n  World!\n\n"
```

Comment: #text and #content are the same, so Aaron got the "Answer" b/c he also took care of the whitespace. +1, though :)

Comment: Plus, he posted his answer first.